# R data.table reverse a cumprod function to get rates of change

Tags: r, data.table

Hi in the following example

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1234)
a = data.table(date=seq(ymd('2001-6-30'),ymd('2003-6-30'),by='weeks'),a=rnorm(105),b=rnorm(105),c=rnorm(105))
```

I get output a little like

```
           date           a           b           c
  1: 2001-06-30 -1.20706575  0.16698928  0.41805782
  2: 2001-07-07  0.27742924 -0.89626463 -0.40023524
  3: 2001-07-14  1.08444118  0.16818539  1.49349310
  4: 2001-07-21 -2.34569770  0.35496826 -1.60708094
  5: 2001-07-28  0.42912469 -0.05210512 -0.41575179
 ---                                               
101: 2003-05-31  0.41452353  0.76046236  1.47171869
102: 2003-06-07 -0.47471847  1.84246363  0.44366490
103: 2003-06-14  0.06599349  1.11236284 -0.42172187
104: 2003-06-21 -0.50247778  0.03266396 -0.04000163
105: 2003-06-28 -0.82599859 -1.11444896 -0.49227997
```

and I can cumulate it (if e.g it were rates of return) using

```
a[,(2:4):=lapply(.SD,function(x) cumprod(x/100+1)),.SDcols=2:4]
```

and get

```
           date         a         b         c
  1: 2001-06-30 0.9879293 1.0016699 1.0041806
  2: 2001-07-07 0.9906701 0.9926923 1.0001615
  3: 2001-07-14 1.0014134 0.9943618 1.0150988
  4: 2001-07-21 0.9779233 0.9978915 0.9987854
  5: 2001-07-28 0.9821198 0.9973716 0.9946329
 ---                                         
101: 2003-05-31 0.8540733 1.0838999 1.1223825
102: 2003-06-07 0.8500188 1.1038704 1.1273621
103: 2003-06-14 0.8505798 1.1161495 1.1226078
104: 2003-06-21 0.8463058 1.1165140 1.1221587
105: 2003-06-28 0.8393153 1.1040711 1.1166346
```

My question is what do I do if I have the output and want to get back to the original rates of return?

```
b=(a[2:105,2:4,with=F]/a[1:104,2:4,with=F]-1)*100
```

followed by a merge seems clunky and I would have difficulty figuring out the merge operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as for the cumprod:

```
a[,(2:4):=lapply(.SD,function(x) c(NA,(tail(x,-1)/head(x,-1)-1)*100)),.SDcols=2:4]
```

Comment: Really easy and straightforward answer. A bit of a 'doh!' moment again on my end. thanks @Roland